# Mock Files with PowerMockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have the following test code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Logger.class, Files.class})
public class TestClass {

  private static final List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("some entry");
  }};
  private static final Path PATH = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    PowerMockito.spy(Files.class);
    PowerMockito.doReturn(LIST).when(Files.class, "readAllLines", PATH, Charset.defaultCharset());
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {}
}
```

The code above throws a "NoSuchFileException" on the last line.
Here is the stacktrace:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/foo   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:317)   at
>   java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:363)    at
>   java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:380)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:108)   at
>   java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2677)    at
>   java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3033)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)
>     at
>   org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:885)
>     at
>   org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:859)
>     at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)   at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:106)
>     at TestClass.setup(TestClass.java:29)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:129)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:93)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

I can't quite get what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please show the actual test as well as a stacktrace.

Comment: I just added the stacktrace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue: the problem is that Files is System class.

> https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mocksystem

Comment: Can you update the link? The PowerMock project moved to github

Comment: I believe the article you linked to has moved to https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/mocksystem